# Print pipe per character instead of newline

Tags: perl, split, newline, pipe

In Perl I do like this now:

```
while (<$pipe>)
{
    print $_;
}
```

But this just gives me the output linewise. How can I make this print lets say, each character, or split by `\r` instead of `\n`. The pipe only feeds me data on newline.

(I want to print the output from another process, and that process is using `\r` to print its process progress, this just ends up as a simple line with 100% for me..)

Comment: Can you try this?  `$/ = "\r";`

Comment: Where should I put this? Before the loop?

Comment: yes. http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/18/variables.html#The_Field_Record_Separators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl has a concept of an “input record separator” `$/` which is usually set to separate lines. You can read the [full documentation here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR). Whenever you read a line/record from a filehandle, data is read until the end of file, or until the current string inside the `$/` variable has been read.

For example: Given the input bytes `aabaa`, and `$/ = "b"`, then `my @records = <$fh>` would produce `('aab', 'aa')`. Note that the separator is always included, but can be removed with `chomp` (regardless of what the separator has been set to).

When reading from a file, the `$/` has to be set before the lines are read, like so:

```
local $/ = "\r"; # "local" avoids overriding this value everywhere
while(my $line = <$pipe>) {
  chomp $line;
  ...
}
```

There are a few special values for `$/`:

- The empty string `$/ = ''` treats a sequence of two or more consecutive `\n`s as the separator (“paragraph mode”).
- If set to a numeric reference, then that number of characters is read: `$/ = \42` (read in 42-character chunks). In this case, one would rather use the `read` function.

Comment: Is there any way to use "\r|\n"? Because after the progress is done each line is delimited with an "\n".

Comment: @DavidEverlöf Nope, only constant strings (plus the special-cased paragraph mode) can be used. Allowing regexes to be used in `$/` comes up regularly on the Perl5-Porters list, but there are a number of good points against that so that nobody ends up implementing anything :-( You can however reassign the record separator if you want, e.g. `$/ = "\n" if $progress_is_done`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Yeah, thats what I had in mind as a next step.. But that can become rather clumsy is arbitrary commands are executed, with different progress output.. Anyway, thanks for the clarification!